# Бот VK, не удаётся вызвать метод без авторизации

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Код вроде работал, но когда написал проверку новых сообщений, стала появляться данная ошибка и даже после возвращения Ctrl+Z к тому моменту, когда всё работало, код не стал работать, выдавая исключение:

> VkNet.Exception.AccessTokenInvalidException: "Метод 'groups.getMembers' нельзя вызывать без авторизации"

код:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using VkNet;
using VkNet.Enums.Filters;
using VkNet.Model;
using VkNet.Utils;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            VkApi vk = new VkApi(); // Объект для работы с API VK

            var webClient = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
            try
            {
                vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
                {
                    ApplicationId = ид_приложения,
                    Login = "логин",
                    Password = "пароль",
                    Settings = Settings.All // Права доступа для токена пользователя https://vk.com/dev/permissions
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            var param = new VkParameters() { }; //Создание объекта для передачи параметров https://vk.com/dev/methods
            param.Add<string>("group_id", "oliverspeaker");
            param.Add<string>("offset", "0");
            param.Add<string>("count", "100");

            var rawJson = JObject.Parse(vk.Call("groups.getMembers", param).RawJson);
            string ids = string.Join(", ", rawJson["response"]["items"].ToArray().Select(x => x.ToString()));

            param = new VkParameters();
            param.Add<string>("user_ids", ids);
            param.Add<string>("fields", "photo_100");

            var dbUsers = JObject.Parse(vk.Call("users.get", param).RawJson)["response"];

            Console.WriteLine("Участники сообщества: ");

            foreach (dynamic item in dbUsers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.first_name} {item.last_name} {item.id} ");
                string urlPhoto = item.photo_100;
                webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(urlPhoto.Replace("?ava=1", "")), $@"photo\photo_{item.first_name}_{item.last_name}_{item.id}.jpg");
            }


            param = new VkParameters();
            param.Add<string>("group_id", "183211821");

            dynamic responseLongPoll = JObject.Parse(vk.Call("groups.getLongPollServer", param).RawJson);

            string json = String.Empty;
            string url = string.Empty;

            Console.WriteLine("server: " + responseLongPoll.response.server.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("key: " + responseLongPoll.response.key.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("ts: " + responseLongPoll.response.ts.ToString());

            url = string.Format("{0}?act=a_check&key={1}&ts=2&wait=1",
                responseLongPoll.response.server.ToString(),
                responseLongPoll.response.key.ToString(),
                responseLongPoll.response.ts.ToString()
                );

            json = webClient.DownloadString(url);

            Console.WriteLine("Json: " + json + "\n");

            //Есть ли сообщения
            var jsonMsg = json.IndexOf(":[]}") > -1 ? "" : $"{json} \n";
            //Коллекция всех сообщений
            var col = JObject.Parse(json)["updates"].ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(col[0].ToString());

            foreach (var item in col)
            {
                if (item["type"].ToString() == "message_new")
                {
                    string token = @"токен";
                    string urlBotMsg = $"https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?v=5.95&access_token={token}&user_id=";

                    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

                    string msg = item["object"]["text"].ToString();

                    Console.WriteLine($"{msg}");

                    webClient.DownloadString(
                        string.Format(urlBotMsg + "{0}&message={1}",
                        item["object"]["from_id"].ToString(),
                        $"В вашем сообщении содержится: {msg.Length}"
                        ));
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Скриншот кода]

Comment: Почему такой странный вызов? Зачем использовать `vk.Call()`, если можно `vk.Groups.GetMembers()`, тогда вам не нужен будет вообще JSON, ибо вернет сразу нужные объекты! ([документация](https://vknet.github.io/vk/groups/getMembers/))

Comment: Да не в этом суть, мне надо авторизацию пройти ВК.